# Why is it not possible to write a null byte in a file using ascii mode with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fp = fs.openSync('binary.txt', "w");

var byte = '\0';
fs.writeSync(fp, byte, null, 'ascii');
```

After executing it when I open the binary.txt file it contains 0x20 and not the null byte as expected.

Now when I use

```
fs.writeSync(fp, byte, null, 'utf-8');
```

I get the wanted null byte in the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't because of the file specifically, but rather then way Node converts ASCII into bytes to write. You'll see the same behavior in this:

```
new Buffer('\0', 'ascii')[0]
// 32
```

If you want to write a NULL byte to a file, don't use a string, just write the byte you want.

```
fs.writeSync(fp, new Buffer([0x00]));
```

Generally when doing file IO, I would recommend only using strings when the content is explicitly text content. If you are doing anything beyond that, stick with `Buffer`s.

#### Specifics

It is actually V8, not Node that performs this conversion. Node exposes the `ascii` encoding as a faster method of converting to binary. To achieve this, it uses V8's `String::WriteOneByte` method and unless explicitly instructed not to, this function automatically converts `'\0'` into `' '`.

Comment: Curious. When would you want to write a NULL byte to a file?

Comment: @jamesemanon Can't say for sure in this case, but many file formats are binary rather than 100% text. For example, you could have a header section with bits/bytes as flags to store metadata, and have a few bytes that specify the starting point of text within the file.

Comment: On the latest node, this doesn't appear to occur anymore with `'\0'` interpreted as a null byte.